# PHP MySQL, mysqli, extensions, drivers, and abstraction layers (what to use)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I just started looking into how to do MySQL DB stuff with PHP, and their seems to be may ways to go about doing this (http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php).

There is the MySQL Improved Extension, a few other SQL specific libraries, as well as a few abstraction layers.

I know it would really depend on how I will be using the DB, but what one/combination would you suggest for general website backend use.

Comment: I would use PDO. [Here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Stay away from the `mysql_*()` functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: Depending on your project and future scalability, you may wish to look at a DB independent framework for the data-layer, such as Doctrine. You need to learn the Doctrine query language, but it's simple enough to pick up, and means if MySQL (which if your project gets sufficiently large) can't handle it, you can switch over to a new RDBMS with little effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PDO extension
PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer, which means that, regardless of which database you're using, you use the same functions to issue queries and fetch data.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php